# what's the meaning of "from up high" & "from down low"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

One of my friend wrote a sentence like this:

> We should have a correct attitude toward Trump. We should not value him from
>   up high or dismiss him from down low.

I'm not sure whether "value from up high" and "dismiss from down low" make sense here. My friend said they mean "think highly of" & "think lowly of." Is he right?

Comment: Your friend isn't a native speaker, his text doesn't conform to valid syntax, AND it has no single unambiguous meaning. I'm therefore closevoting because there's no point in analysing how someone *should* have written something, or what they *might* have meant, when that person isn't around to provide clarification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, your friend is incorrect. The phrases allude to evaluating Trump as god in heaven ("from up high" which I think should really be ["from on high"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20on%20high)) and as the devil in hell ("from down low" which I think should really be "from down below" ).